# How can I make EF Core 3 translate the group by foreign key the same way efcore7 does it?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have the following entities and a database context

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ReceiptId { get; set; }
    public int ItemTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class ItemType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Receipt
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ReceiptInfo { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to get a the list of receipts, but instead of containing the items they contain, I want them to have the `itemType` and the amount of items for each. I have written the following linq query, which works:

```
var result = _databaseContext.Receipts.Select(r => new
            {
                r.Id,
                r.ReceiptInfo,
                ItemInfo = r.Items.GroupBy(item => item.ItemTypeId)
                                  .Select(group => new
                                  {
                                      IdItemType = group.Key,
                                      AmountOfItems = group.Count(),
                                  }).ToList()

            });
```

With EF Core 7, it is translated to the following SQL query:

```
SELECT [r].[Id], [r].[ReceiptInfo], [t].[IdItemType], [t].[AmountOfItems]
FROM [Receipts] AS [r]
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT [i].[ItemTypeId] AS [IdItemType], COUNT(*) AS [AmountOfItems]
     FROM [Items] AS [i]
     WHERE [r].[Id] = [i].[ReceiptId]
     GROUP BY [i].[ItemTypeId]) AS [t]
ORDER BY [r].[Id]
```

Yet, I need to do this in an older project which doesn't support a version older than 3.1 for EF Core.

There it translates the query differently and I get this error

> Column 'Receipts.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of EF Core 3.1, you have to postprocess loaded detail items on the client side:

```cs
var rawData = _databaseContext.Receipts.Select(r => new
    {
        r.Id,
        r.ReceiptInfo,
        RawItemInfo = r.Items.Select(item => new
        {
            IdItemType = item.ItemTypeId
        }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();

var result = rawData
    .Select(r => new
    {
        r.Id,
        r.ReceiptInfo,
        ItemInfo = r.RawItemInfo
            .GroupBy(item => item.ItemTypeId)
            .Select(group => new
            {
                IdItemType = group.Key,
                AmountOfItems = group.Count(),
            }).ToList()
    });
```

Comment: Note that this may pull a lot more data (`item.ItemTypeId`s) than the final output requires. If there aren't too many items that won't be a problem.

Comment: @GertArnold, your answer is better than mine, but probably OP has hidden some other details.

Comment: Well, yours looks more like the original query, which may be a plus.

Answer (score 1):

As you see, `GroupBy` support has improved drastically in EFC 7. EFC 3 only supports GroupBy with aggregates at the query root.

Therefore, to make it run in EFC 3 you need to force the query into the supported shape. To get the same grouping level, the query starts at `Items` and groups + aggregates once over three elements instead of two:

```cs
var result = _databaseContext.Items
    .GroupBy(item => new { item.ReceiptId, item.Receipt.ReceiptInfo, item.ItemTypeId })
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Id = group.Key.ReceiptId,
        ReceiptInfo = group.Key.ReceiptInfo,
        IdItemType = group.Key.ItemTypeId,
        NrOfItems = group.Count(),
    })
```

That returns the same data as the original query and does the reduction of data (aggregate) in the database. To get the same result shape, it needs some post-processing in-memory (i.e. after calling `AsEnumerable()`):

```cs
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Receipt.ReceiptInfo })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.Key.Id,
        g.Key.ReceiptInfo,
        ItemInfo = g.Select(x => new { x.IdItemType, x.NrOfItems })
       
    });
```

This requires adding a navigation property `Item.Receipt`.

Comment: What if the Receipt had much more properties? Would I need to add them all one by one in the GroupBy? This seems a little inconvenient.

Comment: If it's (nearly) all of them, you could group by `item.Receipt` and select the eligible properties in the final `Select`, otherwise, yes, for performance it may be better to list the properties twice.